# VS Setup project in VS2015 + git

Tags: git, visual-studio, setup-project, vdproj, visual-studio-setup-proje

I've got an old project and solution which I've figured out how to build in VS 2015 while using our old TFS version control. Since then we've moved all of our projects to Git. These setup projects require that the project be checked out (which I think is some sort of TFS legacy) if you want to make changes to the metadata (and other things?).

Is there a way to disable this or to fool VS to think that the project is checked out? I need to change the version and the GUID no this project.

Comment: Why are you not checking the files out to make these changes?  Are you not going to check the changes back in?

Comment: It's a checked out project, and yes the Idea was to check out and commit/push the changes in. The issue is that there's no "check out for edit" feature in Git and this type of project seems to assume you're running TFS. I circumvented this by opening the solution "offline" in another version of VS and then commited the changes to Git. Git - of course - didn't care about it being modified externally.